# Can't load data from CoreData into tableview

Tags: ios, database, swift, uitableview, core-data

I'm learning how to use CoreData. I have a tableView with an add button, which segues to a view with just a textfield and a save button. When the button is pressed, the string in the textfield is saved in a CoreData database:

```
    @IBOutlet weak var name: UITextField!
@IBAction func onSave(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        saveItem(name.text!)
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }

    private func saveItem(itemName: String)
    {
       let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext
        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Item", inManagedObjectContext: managedContext)
        let item = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedContext)
        item.setPrimitiveValue(itemName, forKey: "name")

        do {
            try managedContext.save()
            listItems.append(item)


        }catch let error {
            print(error)
    }
```

The tableView file has the Controller class and a global array of NSManagedObject:
Here is the relevant code:

```
var listItems = [NSManagedObject]()//outside the class



override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) { //in the tableviewcontroller class

        let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext

        let fetch = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Item")

        do {
            let results = try managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetch)
            listItems = results as! [NSManagedObject]
            //EDIT
            for item in listItems {
              print(item)
        }
        } catch let error {
            print(error)
        }


        self.tableView.reloadData()

    }
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        let item = listItems[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = item.valueForKey("name") as? String
        return cell

    }
```

The database is very simple: an Entity named `Item` with a `name` attribute

This, however, doesn't work. When I press the save button, no new rows are added. If I remove all the code in viewWillAppear but `self.tableView.reloadData()`, the  rows are created but when I relaunch the app they aren't there.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Reload the table view always **after** changing the data source array (`listItems`)

Comment: @vadian That is how I originally had it, it still doesn't work, but I have edited my post

Comment: It seems to work for me. maybe the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: I don't using a global variable is very good practice and might lead to problems. Also in your code its content gets replaced every time the view appears.