# NSManagedObject: data <fault>

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data

I'm learning CoreData, and I can't seem to fetch the data and load it into my tableview.

Here is my previous question with the full code in it: [Can't load data from CoreData into tableview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39436520/cant-load-data-from-coredata-into-tableview)

For debugging, I'm printing out the NSManagedObjects in my array, but the data in them is printed as data . However, there are a lot of NSManagedObjects being printed out. My table is blank though.
How can I print out the data in the NSManagedObjects (if I can)?
Or is there another Issue?

Comment: I find it a lot easier to deal with managed objects if I create `NSManagedObject` subclasses for all my custom entities.  That way, I can refer to the content as regular object properties (including creating a `description` method).

Comment: Is this a different question from the one you linked? Why post another question when the first one wasn't solved yet?

Comment: @rmaddy I looked up this question and all the information I found seemed outdated (obj-c), so I thought I'd post this one as a separate post for future references